# The value of $a$ besides $1$ for which $\gamma =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^a}-\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x^a}dx\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that Euler-Mascheroni constant is given by
$$\gamma =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}dx\right)$$
I am not sure whether there exists a value $a$ besides $1$ such that the equation below holds. 
$$\gamma =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^a}-\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x^a}dx\right)$$
I did some calculation for $0<a<1$, but as I set $n$ bigger and bigger, all the results seem to fall apart. For example, when $n=9999$, the result seems fine.[image]
However, as $n$ gets larger, Wolfram Alpha starts to give me two different results. I am not sure whether it's because there is just no such value as $a$ (I am confident there is one), or is Wolfram Alpha doing the wrong calculation. I need some assistance.
[image]

Comment: The limit equals $\frac{1}{1-a}+\zeta(a)$.

Comment: Good idea! I see what you are saying. Let me try that first. If you are right, I will try to find a proof for your claim.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539608/evaluating-zeta-frac12-as-an-integral-zeta-frac12-frac12?rq=1) may be useful.

Comment: So I tried your proposal of $\frac{1}{1-a}+\zeta{(a)}$. It seems like only 1 satisfy the limit. There are no other values, but I am still not convinced

Comment: _Mathematica_ agrees with the proposal. Since `Catalan` $\in(0,1)$, we can use a trick. Input:`Limit[Sum[1/n^Catalan, {n, 1, x}] - Integrate[1/n^Catalan, {n, 1, x}],
  x -> \[Infinity]]` and output is $\frac{-C \zeta (C)+\zeta (C)+1}{1-C}$.

Comment: Could you explain more about what Catalan is? Also, what is the approximate value of $C$?

Comment: Catalan $\approx 0.915966$ is a constant. I used it to force Mathematica assume a "variable" is in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I checked it on Wolfram Alpha, but it gives me the approximation of 0.571 instead of $\gamma \approx 0.577$.

Comment: If your method of checking is using a very big upper bound, then this method is not so valid since the integral and the sum converge very slowly.

Comment: Yes, I tried using a big upper bound. You might be right, but I am not sure if Mathematica is reliable. I am trying to find a rigorous proof to show that there exists a value Catalan such that the equation holds.

Comment: Or disprove the existence of such value Catalan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could be answered with a simple graph from Wolfram Alpha:
[image]

> The graph shows that there is no value between $0$ and $1$ for which the equation equals $\gamma$, but there are many trivial solutions when $a<0$.